# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError with expm

Tags: java

I am trying to compute the matrix exponential for a square matrix using jblas library it defined on the attached website http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/MatrixFunctions.html
but I am not sure how to do it I wrote the following code according to the website I should define it as a method but I am not sure how I can do it Any help would be appreciated

```
package org.jblas;

import java.util.Random;

public class MatrixFunctions {

public static  Double expm(Double A[][]) {
    return expm(A);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Double Q[][]=new Double[3][3];
    Random random=new Random();
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
            Q[i][j]=random.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    Double B;
    B=expm(Q);
    System.out.println(B[1][1]);
}
}
```

and I keep having this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.jblas.MatrixFunctions.expm(MatrixFunctions.java:8)
    at org.jblas.MatrixFunctions.expm(MatrixFunctions.java:8)
```

Comment: The method `expm` has a recursive call without an exit condition. this causes an infinite loop and  the stack overflow. What is the purpose of the method `expm`?
}

Comment: Sure. `expm` has only one line that does nothing else but recursively calling itself unconditionally.

Comment: Why is your code in package `org.jblas`? There is a [`MatrixFunctions`](http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/MatrixFunctions.html) class in jblas which has an [`expm`](http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/MatrixFunctions.html#expm(org.jblas.DoubleMatrix)) method that takes a [`DoubleMatrix`](http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/DoubleMatrix.html), and a constructor for the latter that takes a `double[][]` as a parameter. Are you trying to *use* that or *rewrite* that?

Comment: Also, there is no reason to use `Double` here instead of `double`, and `B` is just a number, not a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment how I can define the MatrixFunctions class and use the expm method Please note that I just start with java last week so I really appreciate if you can post an example of how expm method can be used thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the assumption that you are not really trying to recreate the JBLAS package, but instead simply use it.

First, remove the `package` declaration or change it to something appropriate:

```
package com.example.mymatrixtest;
```

Second, import the JBLAS classes (and make sure you have JBLAS on your classpath):

```
import org.jblas.MatrixFunctions;
import org.jblas.DoubleMatrix;
```

Third, rename your class to something that isn't the same as a JBLAS class name, which would only cause confusion:

```
public class MatrixTest {
```

And, finally, create your matrix using `double`, not `Double`, create a `DoubleMatrix` from it, and call the JBLAS `expm` method:

```
double[][] q = . . . // your logic to create the matrix here
DoubleMatrix qmatrix = new DoubleMatrix(q); // create a JBLAS object
DoubleMatrix b = MatrixFunctions.expm(qmatrix); // let JBLAS calculate expm
```

You can use the [`get(int, int)`](http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/DoubleMatrix.html#get(int,%20int)) method to access individual elements of matrix `b`:

```
System.out.println(b.get(1, 1));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment but when I tried to import both MatrixFunctions and DoubleMatrix I get the following error "The import org.jblas.MatrixFunctions cannot be resolved" I added the JBLAS package as referenced libraries from jblas-1.2.3-sources.jar I really appreciate your help thank you again

Comment: I think you need the jblas-1.2.3.jar file, not the "sources" jar file which only contains the source code, not the compiled .class files.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfect but I have last question how can I deal with b as a matrix I mean how can I get for example b[1][1] element

Comment: I didn't notice it before because in your code you had `expm` returning a `Double`, but `expm` actually returns a `DoubleMatrix`. You can use the `get` method to access individual matrix elements, for example, `b.get(1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static  Double expm(Double A[][]) {
    return expm(A);
}
```

This just calls itself over and over and over until the stack overflows.

Comment: Thank you guys but how I can stop this I am sorry but I start working on java just last week expm should take the matrix exponential any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: @AhmadGhaziAltarabsheh How to fix your method will depend on what it's supposed to do.  Right now it doesn't do *anything* except call itself over and over again.  Try editing your question to describe the **purpose** of `expm()`, including some **sample inputs** and the **expected result** for each input.

Comment: I suspect you can find the [purpose of `expm` here](http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/MatrixFunctions.html#expm(org.jblas.DoubleMatrix)).

Answer (score 1):

You just re-call to this function, until stack memory will full

`public static  Double expm(Double A[][]) {
    return expm(A);    //remove of modify this line 
                       //because this line will re-call your function
                       //need to return Double value
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursion loop

```
public static  Double expm(Double A[][]) {
    return expm(A);
}
```

You just re-call your recursive function every time without changing the parameter.

Every time you make a new function call, extra data gets pushed onto the call stack, and eventually, it's too much for the system to handle, and a stack overflow exception is thrown.

If you want the exception to go away, you're going to have to change your `expm` function to eventually stop calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

A stackoverflow exception usually occurs when you call so many functions that the JVM can't keep track of all the state.  99% of the time this occurs when a function calls itself in an infinite loop.  That's happening in your case:

```
public static  Double expm(Double A[][]) {
    return expm(A);
}
```

This method is calling itself over and over again.  Nothing ever stops it.  I'm not really sure what this function is supposed to do so I can't suggest a specific solution for you, but in general, to fix this problem you have an if statement that will eventually stop the infinite loop.

To help you visualize your problem, I'm going to show what you're doing as if you weren't using recursion:

```
public static  Double expm1(Double A[][]) {
    return expm2(A);
}

public static  Double expm2(Double A[][]) {
    return expm3(A);
}

public static  Double expm3(Double A[][]) {
    return expm4(A);
}

//and it keeps going forever
```

As you can see, this will never end.  Eventually you'll run out of memory and it'll be reported as a `StackOverflowError`